# Find entire function $f$ s.t. $f(n)=|n|$ and $f'(n)=\text{sign}(n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I want to find an entire function $f$ such that $$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}: f(n)=|n| \text{ and } f'(n)=\text{sgn}(n)$$

---

My attempt:

My first idea was to use $\cos(2\pi x)x$ because it's always equal to $x$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and entire. But since I have to map $f(n)=|n|$, I defined my function as it follows:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \cases{\cos(2\pi z)x \quad \text{ for } x\geq 0 \\ -\cos(2\pi x)x \quad \text{ for } x< 0}
\end{align*}

This worked very well with the second condition, because $\forall x_0\in \mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}:$

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\cos(2\pi x)x - x_0}{x-x_0}\overset{\text{L'Hospital}}{=} \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} (\cos(2\pi x) - 2\pi x \sin(2\pi x)) = \cos(2\pi x_0)= 1
\end{align*}

and $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}^-:$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} =...= -\cos(2\pi x_0) = -1$$

So the only problem I have left is the critical point $z = 0$ because it's not differentiable there. (See picture to better understand it) [image]

So I thought of using a polynomial to interpolate my desired behavior in the interval $[-0.5,0.5]$, because I saw there were extreme points.

Using linear algebra I found a polynomial of 4th degree $p(x)=4x^4-3x^2$ that satisfies the conditions for $0$ and has the same derivative in $-0.5$, $0.5$ as $f$.

So I redefined $f$:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \cases{\cos(2\pi x)x \quad \text{ for } x\geq 0.5 \\ 4x^4-3x^2 \quad \text{ for } -0.5<x<0.5\\
-\cos(2\pi x)x \quad \text{ for } x< -0.5}
\end{align*}

This function should satisfy all conditions and is entire. Is this alright? Have I missed an easier/more obvious approach?

Comment: the function above is not entire -

Comment: @Conrad How so?

Comment: @Quotenbanane: Do you know the identity theorem? If $f(x) = \cos(2 \pi x)x$ for $x \ge 0.5$ then $f(z) = \cos(2 \pi z)z$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: it is not even $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$g(z)=(\frac {\sin {\pi z}}{\pi})^2\sum_{m \in \mathbb Z}\text{sgn}(m)(z-m)^{-2}$$ where as usual $\text{sgn}(0)=0$, is entire as the series converges locally uniformly away from the integers, while for $z=m \ne 0$ the series without the $\text{sgn}(m)(z-m)^{-2}$ term converges locally uniformly, while $(\frac {\sin {\pi z}}{\pi})^2(z-m)^{-2}$ is also analytic.

By construction, we have $g(m)=\text{sgn}(m)$, while it is an easy exercise to see that $g'(m)=0$ since the only thing to prove is that the derivative of $(\frac {\sin {\pi z}}{\pi})^2(z-m)^{-2}$ is zero at $m$ and that follows from the Taylor series of the sine function as when squared it has no degree three term.

Then $f(z)=zg(z)$ satisfies $f(n)=|n|$ and $f'(n)=g(n)+ng'(n)=g(n)=\text{sgn}(n)$

Comment: OK thank you. I've researched a lot and I think your answer is really good. The only thing I couldn't entirely understand is the argument that this function is entire. 
So we need to check that the function is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{C}$? I get why it's that way for $z\neq n$, but for $z=m$, why can we look at it without the $\text{sgn}(m)(z-m)^{-2}$ term?

Comment: Because the $\sin^2 \pi z$ term has a double zero at all integers so takes care of the $1/(z-m)^2$ factor at each $m$ - if you prefer, the ratio of the two has an analytic extension at $m$

Comment: there are similar but slightly simpler entire interpolations of the sign function (one can do a type $\pi$ such - in other words with factor $\sin \pi z$ rather than its square -  rather than the type $2\pi$ here as $\sin^2 \pi z$ is asymptotic to $e^{2\pi |z|}$ for $z=iy$ say, so it's said to have type $2\pi$), but here we also need the derivative to be zero at integers, so that kind of forces a minimal type $2\pi$ solution by some general (though non trivial) results

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!